# Produce list of all files to delete and all to add between two git commits

Tags: git, diff

I have an old system i have to deal with ands the interface is garbage.  I cannot re-name or move files.  I must delete the old location and add the new location.

I do this by providing a list of all the files to remove and then all the files to add / update

when I re-name file and commit that in git it counts as a `rename` operation so when i run

```
git diff SHA1 SHA2 --name-only
```

I get a list of all deletes, add and renames in one.  If i run

```
git diff SHA1 SHA2 --name-only --diff-filter=R
```

I get the end result of the opperation (what the file was renamed **to** but not what it was renamed **from**).  If i run

I get deleted files but not the files that were renamed **to** something else.

i *do not* need this in a single command and I can produce overlaps and de-dupe the output later.

Help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In git there is no such thing as a rename operation.  When `diff` reports a rename, it is seeing a delete at one path and an add at another, calculating that the new file is "similar enough" to what was deleted that it was probably just a rename, and inferring that you'd like it reported as such.

If you don't want them reported as renames, but rather want the delete and the add reported separately, then you can say

```
git diff SHA1 SHA2 --name-only --no-renames
```

More usefully, you could say

```
git diff SHA1 SHA2 --name-status --no-renames
```

and the lines for deleted files will start with `D`, and the lines for added files will start with `A`.

On the other hand, if you're using `--name-status`, then depending on what you're doing with the output, perhaps it would be ok not to turn off rename detection; then you'd get something like

```
$ git diff SHA1 SHA2 --name-status

R100   file1   file2
```

where IIRC `R100` means "renamed with 100% content match"

But then again, if having the entries on separate lines works well for you, then turning off rename detection may be more efficient (especially if many deletes and adds actually occur).

I guess one last permutation:  If you really want just the list of filenames, then you could make one list of adds

```
git diff SHA1 SHA2 --name-only --no-renames --diff-filter=A
```

and one of deletes

```
git diff SHA1 SHA2 --name-only --no-renames --diff-filter=D
```

Comment: This is 100% correct and very helpful.  Fixed my issue perfectly.